# Get a specific element out of overlay in position: fixed

Tags: css, overlay, css-position

I have a sidebar with position:fixed; on the right side of my template. I also have an overlay for the whole page. I want one element out of the sidebar(a list element) to be marked as active and in front of the overlay. 
I have an example on js fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/t93ew/

HTML:

```
<body>

<div id="fixed">
<ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="google.com">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="google.com">Test2</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
<div class="overlay"></div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#fixed{
position:fixed;
text-align: center;
right:0;
background:#fff;
height: 100%;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px #888;
width: 100px;
}
.overlay {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
z-index:10;
    }
ul li{
background: #000;
}

.active{
background-color:#fff;
position:relative;
z-index:11;
}
```

If i use float:right; for the fixed sidebar instead of position:fixed; it works like a charm. But i need the position fixed because the sidebar needs to scroll with the page and have a 100% height.

Is there any way to have a z-index inside of a fixed element?

EDIT: Like Chris mentioned its only doesn't work in Chrome

Comment: Your items are infront of the overlay already?

Comment: Try adding a wrapper around the whole snippet and set it's height to something fixed like 300px, than change your sidebar back to float right.

Comment: like Chris mentioned it looks like a Chrome problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a Google Chrome bug, if you try it in other browsers it should work.

If you set `#fixed` to `position: absolute;` then it won't be behind `.overlay` anymore.

Comment: Ok you are right it works in other browsers.. Any idea how i can make a fix for chrome? Or is it really a bug?